# The meaning of some fields in structure of udis86 object

Tags: c, disassembly

Could you explain please what these fields mean

```
uint8_t     inp_curr;
uint8_t     inp_ctr;
uint8_t     inp_fill;
uint64_t            pc;
```

in  struct ud (udis86 object)? 
I notice they are always getting the identical values.

Comment: Please give some more context about the problem, or tag accordingly.

Comment: Better you ask on the udis86 forum instead since your questions are specific to the tool.

Comment: @0xF1 the problem is there are no comments to these fields...

Comment: @claptrap have they a forum? I hope so